# Why do I get "error: directory jot empty" when shows empty but contained 1tb of data

Tags: data-recovery, directory

A directory in my external drive contained 1tb data, and when accidentally unplugging, the directory shows empty when opened and in properties...

When I go to delete directory, shows "error: directory not empty"

How to resolve this?

Comment: What OS are you using?  How is the drive formatted?  Were you writing anything to the drive when you unplugged it?

Comment: Ubuntu, the drive still works so I think it's altrady fat32 formatted (for use over most of systems). I was editing a .ses file created from Photorec... but the editor froze so I force quitted and accidentally unplugged it... no only the specific directory seems to show empty where the see file wad

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to retrieve a lot of information about your drive when it is connected, and hopefully this will give you some ideas.  I will list some command-line based tools.

### First thought

```
rm /direcotry/path -rf
```

...should solve your problem with this direcotry: it should really remove it for good.  If you need to, you can precede the above command with sudo; and you have to be VERY cautious, because you will remove almost anyting you ask it to.  Also, type `-rf` at the end, so if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> accidentally, prematurely, you will not "force" and "recursively" over something you did not intend.

However, if you feel like experimenting more - there is more for you below:

### 1) Info about ALL disk devices

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

...will list device name, size and partitions (and more).  In the last column you get the partition type.

I think that fat32 is not the optimal choice for large disks, however, it is fairly standard everywhere.  You could use ntfs - nowadays Ubuntu also supports it to some extent.

### 2) Info about mounted devices

```
sudo df -h
sudo df -hi
```

...will pint info about mounted filesystems together with the name of a device that contins it.  You have **bytes** (default) used, you have **inodes** (specified by -i parameter) which are correlated to the number of files on the disk (not only a size matters, bu also the number of entries in the file allocation table). "h" for human readible units.

```
cd /directory/path
du -hs
```

...will let you know the summary of that is in `/direcotry/path`.  "s" for summary rather than a complete list and "h" for human readible units.

```
du -ms *   | sort -n
du -ms */* | sort -n
```

...this is the protagon of all console-based disk-free-space checks. My favourite. I love how it shows me the biggest items in the current path.  By using `asterisk`/`asterisk` instead of `asterisk` you will compare all sub-items that are in the current location.

```
ls -lah
```

...is for viewing the directory too.  "h" as above, **"a" includes hidden files/dirs**, "l" shows access rights and ownership info.  Especially "a" flag may be of interest in your case.

### 3) Still nothing? Format the drive

Copy your precious data elsewhere and format the drive over again. After all, the system might have suffered some damages due to the power loss.

```
sudo unmount /dev/name0    # carefully select the device
```

CAREFULLY CHOOSE THE DEVICE.  If you make a typo at some point, you may loose all you data and OS, and your machine will stop working.

```
sudo fsck /dev/name0
```

...has the potential to repair your disk whis HAS TO BE unmounted.  After fsck finishes, you can remount your drive by `mount /dev/name0 /any/path/you/want` and verify, but sometimes you have to replace the filesystem internals - keep on reading.

```
sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/name0
```

...it overwrites the file system the disk already has.  This could also be `mkfs.vfat` for fat32 or (what I prefer) `mkfs.ext3`.